# What is the best way to work with manually Excel collected data from different sources?

Tags: excel, powerbi, data-collection

I have been tasked with creating Power BI KPI reports and the data to feed those reports comes from different sources and is collected manually.

There is one person responsible per KPI. That person collects the KPI's data monthly and puts it in an Excel file. Then, that person sends the xlsm file to another person, who is responsible of organizing multiple KPI's into one Excel file. Ultimately, that person sends it to me and I use that xlsm file to create the report. The same process goes on per area of the company (6 in total) every month.

As you can see, there is a lot of copy/paste going on which can indice errors.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment, so I will explain here what I think you can do.
I will ignore the collecting of data by person responsible per KPI.
You can use a database connection, using plugins or VBA, to send the Excel data to a database. Create a VBA Excel file with a script to send the data to a database and there you can do whatever you want. The most important thing that you need to do, is limit the 'columns' of data that Excel will have, or find a way to get the data directly from the source, using an API or whatever you find.

Another approach is creating a web form to send data directly to you, but i don't know if this is possible in your case.

It's the only thing I can think, given the limited options.